# Blender glass shader adds a weird shading to the edges

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I was trying to create a realistic plastic , transparent shader. 
I just mixed a few nodes at first and it was great till later some noises and weird shading took over the edges of the model.
I would like the edges to look the same as the inner the rest of the model
Here are some images.[image: This how it looks plus the node setup. The last node is a glass node with roughness set to 0]

Comment: try to add thickness with the solidify modifier, as otherwise the whole bottle will be rendered as one block of glass (plastic)

Comment: thank you soo much Sir